# how to output string of struct which belong to an vector array?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

i met an weird problem:first i need scanf function to input a special stream,like this:`scanf("%s %4d/%2d/%2d", &temp.name, &temp.year, &temp.month, &temp.day);`,the type of temp is a struct which conclude four variable:

```
struct citizen{
   char* name;
   int year;
   int month;
   int day;
}
```

actually i use string type instead of char *, but scanf seem not to support it. i creat an vector, and push temp into this vector, when i end up my input task, i want to output the variable:name of the struct, but program always goes wrong and break down, there is my full code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator> 
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct citizen{
    char* name;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    bool operator < (const citizen &A) const{
        return (year*365+month*30+day) < (A.year*365+A.month*30+A.day);
    }
};
int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<citizen> ci; 
    citizen temp;
    int bb = 2014*365+9*30+6;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%s %4d/%2d/%2d", &temp.name, &temp.year, &temp.month, &temp.day);
        bool p = 1;
        int bt = temp.year*365+temp.month*30+temp.day; 
        if(bt>bb)
            p = 0;
        else if((bb-bt) > 200*365)
            p = 0;
        if(p)
            ci.push_back(temp);
    }
    printf("%s", ci[0].year);       //1st method to ouput
    for(vector<citizen>::const_iterator it = ci.begin(); it != ci.end(); it++) //2nd method to ouput
        cout << it->name;
    //but both goes wrong       
    return 0;
}
```

any idea?

Comment: `%s` expects a `char *` pointing to a buffer of sufficient size. You're passing in a `char **`, whose pointee is uninitialized.

Comment: Use scanf_s("%c %4d/%2d/%2d", &temp.name, &temp.year, &temp.month, &temp.day);

Comment: Use std::cin and std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the statement

```
scanf("%s %4d/%2d/%2d", &temp.name, &temp.year, &temp.month, &temp.day);
```

you have *two* major problems:

1. When scanning for strings, the `scanf` function expects a pointer to the first character, which should be of type `char*`. You pass `&temp.name` which is a pointer *to the pointer* and is of type `char**`.
2. Once you fix that, the pointer you pass with `temp.name` is pointer to... I don't know, and neither do you. It is uninitialized, will have an *indeterminate* and seemingly random value. You need to use an array of characters instead, or allocate memory dynamically and assign the result to the pointer.

Of course, this wouldn't be a problem at all if you used standard C++ input with `std::cin` and `std::string` instead.